# How can I enter more than a 6 digit PIN for Bluetooth pairing on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: bluetooth, 17.04

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04, and want to pair my BT modem to my laptop.
When I get to entering the BT pin, I am allowed 6 digits, but my code is 10 digits long. How may I enter it?
I have confirmed this is the problem by connecting the modem to my phone without issue.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.
The modem is a Trust 56K modem - model 14019
Thanks

Comment: And that BT modem is...?

Comment: The modem is a Trust 56K modem - model 14019 Thanks